# Yii2: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Trying to UPDATE table from different model-

This is my query

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE create_job SET status=$model->status WHERE job_code=$model->job_code")

                ->execute();
```

**Table in which I want to update-**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS create_job ( job_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
status varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
job_code varchar(11) NOT NULL, 
client_code varchar(11) NOT NULL, ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

getting above error, whats wrong with it?

Comment: it clearly tell that `in your table no column with name status is there.`

Comment: there is column called status

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `create_job` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `job_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: try once:- `$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE create_job SET `status`=$model->status WHERE `job_code`=$model->job_code")

                ->execute();` use back trics on column name status and jb_code.

Comment: Getting error-

`Undefined variable: app`

Comment: this is no where related to your previous problem

Comment: query is right don't know why its not working, is there any other syntax for update in yii2?

Comment: check it on google. i am not very good in yi2.

Comment: sorry that i am not able to help you more. but i hope you will get solution on google. Or may be someone give you answer here only.

Comment: its ok mate, I will update if I found out..

Comment: Sure. i will see that also. one thing that as you stated `Undefined variable: app`. check that the variable `$app` is initialized and created properly or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE create_job SET status='$model->status' WHERE job_code='$model->job_code'")->execute();
```